# Sci-fi book about identical twin girls, one sent to space, the other on earth feels the same feelings

Tags: story-identification, novel

I read the book about 1965. Involves identical twin girls. One was sent into space. The twin on earth responded/had the same feelings as the sister in space.

Comment: This is super vague, can you please add some more details? And even check out [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9335/21267) to see if it helps jog your memory.

Comment: Plot-wise, [_Ship-Sister, Star-Sister_](http://www.majipoor.com/work.php?id=1018) by Robert Silverberg seems to be a good match, but (a) it was published in 1973, and (b) it's a novelette, not a novel (it was expanded into the novel _Starborne_, but only in 1996.)

Answer (score 8):

Some of the later ['Chris Godfrey of Unexa'](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pe.cgi?2814) series by Hugh Walters has a pair of telepathic girl twins who provide communication between the ship and Earth.

Comment: I was thinking of that myself. The first Walters book I ever read was *Mission to Mercury* in which the young male heroes first meet the girl who will be part of their crew on the trip to Mercury. I think the excuse was that when you got so close to the sun, its radiation would scramble any attempt to maintain communications with Earth via regular radio. So having a telepathic communications officer could be very useful.

Comment: Did this include the "had the same feelings" element mentioned in the question and lacking in *Time for the Stars*? You get my upvote anyway. This seems like a better fit.

Comment: Yes. At one point the people on the ship are preparing to enter hibernation pods, and they forget their pre-sleep injections. The girl feels her sister on Earth having hers; which reminds them.

Comment: Yes! I remember reading several in this series when I was in elementary school (5th and 6th grades). Made me love science fiction. My neighbor's daughter worked for NASA as a mathematician and programmer, and I would banter about space travel with her at Christmas visits.

Answer (score 4):

Despite the lack of detail I will guess this is [Time for the Stars, by Robert Heinlein.](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_for_the_Stars) It was published in 1956.

Pat and Tom are identical twins who are found to be able to communicate telepathically. Tom is sent to space on a colony ship while Pat remains behind, providing a means of communicating between ship and Earth.

Unlike the question, Pat and Tom are boys. There are other identical twins split the same way, who are girls.

Comment: There are, however, twin girl pair communicators on the same ship as Tom, and on other ships.

Comment: Good point. I'd forgotten that.